# User's AllMessages is gone in latest preview of the sdk

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

Also Users[{id}].Chats.AllMessages() is gone on 0.30.0-preview
when using 0.29 it's there..
Was it moved?

Comment: Could you please share more details on what your trying?

Comment: On earlier versions what I did is:
graphClient.Users[{id}].Chats.AllMessages().Request().GetAsync()
but on 0.30-preview it seems the .Chats.AllMessages() is gone...
Error CS1061 'IUserChatsCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AllMessages' and no accessible extension method 'AllMessages' accepting a first argument of type 'IUserChatsCollectionWithReferencesRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you trying to list all messages of user using graph API? If yes could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)? try if that helps.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT your link is the messages in a Mail Box, I'm trying to get all chat messages in Teams. this is achieved by using the Teams Export API.
anyway, my question was answered on their github page as I mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was removed on 0.30 preview and added back on 0.31
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/184